# Mounting a folder in Dask distributed AWS ECS/EC2 cluster

Tags: amazon-ecs, dask, dask-distributed, dask-kubernetes, aws-ec2-instance-connect

I am using dask distributed package to create a EC2/ECS cluster, I want to read the ML models within the workers, something like

```
def read_model(model_path):
    model = pickle.load(model_path)
    return model

future = client.submit(read_model, model_path)
model = future.result()
```

How do I mount/volume the local folder while creating the ECS/EC2 cluster using python.

tried to look into the parameters provided
[here](https://cloudprovider.dask.org/en/latest/aws.html#dask_cloudprovider.aws.EC2Cluster)

Answer (score 0):

As answered in https://dask.discourse.group/t/mounting-a-folder-in-dask-distributed-aws-ecs-ec2-cluster/1591/3, if by local folder you mean a folder on your personal computer, then you won't be able to mount it on a ECS or EC2 instance.